# malformed text: Hack attempt

Tags: security

Someone has entered `eval&#40;chr(112&#41;.chr(114).chr(105).chr(110).chr(116).chr(40).chr(39).chr(49).chr(55).chr(73).chr(53).chr(51).chr(48).chr(86).chr(65).chr(117).chr(52).chr(39).chr(41).chr(59));` and `MTUwNTYzMDAyNQ{${eval&#40;chr(112&#41;.chr(114).chr(105).chr(110).chr(116).chr(40).chr(39).chr(49).chr(55).chr(73).chr(53).chr(51).chr(48).chr(86).chr(65).chr(117).chr(52).chr(39).chr(41).chr(59))}}`

in sign-up form in our website. Can someone explain this code? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a Cross-Site-Scripting ([XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS))) attack. The author of the input tried to execute code (here: the eval() function) that entered into the form.

### Explanation:

Typical measures agains XSS are input validation and proper encoding of user input. Since input validation is not always done well, there are many ways attackers try to to circumvent it, as described here: [XSS Filter Evasion](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet). One well known strategy is to encode certain characters, like quotes or brackets, to pass checks based on blacklists. In your case, the whole statement has no quotes, i.e. if your input validation would just check the input for quotes to detect XSS attempts, the attack would still work.

If you need any hints how to prevent XSS attacks, the [OWASP Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) is a good starting point.

### Translation:

In the input you provided, the attacker encoded the javascript eval() function using HTML codes (e.g. `&#40;`) and ASCII indices. The first part would translate to `eval(print('...`. You can translate the rest if you take any ASCII table and look up the character numbers.

Comment: It says print('17I530VAu4'). Could you please explain, what does '17I530VAu4' does?